# Ahead of origin/master, how to put commits onto a new branch?

Tags: git

I'm in a state where I'm `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.` because I forgot to make a new branch before editing and committing.

How do I make a new branch that is comprised of these two commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can branch out from your current `master`:

```
$ git branch my_new_branch
```

and then reset your `master` back to `origin/master`:

```
$ git reset origin/master --hard
```

Comment: Do I do step 2 while on `my_new_branch`?

Comment: @Dave no. Both these steps should be executed from your `master`. Note that the first step creates `my_new_branch`, but does not switch over to it.

Comment: Nope step 2 you have to perform in master branch

Answer (score 2):

[Mureinik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47445212/1256452) is right (and upvoted) but it might help to have a little visual illustration of what's going on here.

In Git, branch names don't really *mean* all that much, in a sense.  What they do is "point to" (contain the raw commit-hash-ID of) *one particular commit*.  It's the commits themselves that are important.  Commits are (mostly) permanent and (entirely) unchangeable: once made, the commit whose hash is `deadc0ffee...` or whatever, is that commit forever.  But a name like `master` or `branch`: *those* can change.

Each commit, meanwhile, "points back to" (stores the big ugly hash ID of) its previous commit.  So if you're on `master` and have some series of commits—instead of writing out big ugly hash IDs, we'll use single letters here—they look a bit like this:

```
... <--E <--F <--G   <-- master
```

Since the internal arrows cannot be changed, and always point backwards, we can just draw them like this instead:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master
```

Now if you add a new commit, it will point back to the *previous* tip of `master`, and `master` will point to it:

```
...--E--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Then you make the second one:

```
...--E--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

Note that `master` just keeps advancing, as we add more commits.  But `origin/master` pointed to `G` before, and still does, so we really should draw this instead:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- origin/master
            \
             H--I   <-- master
```

What you want to do at this point is make a *new* name `newbranch` or `feature` or whatever, pointing to commit `I`:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- origin/master
            \
             H--I   <-- master, newbranch
```

and then "re-set" `master` so that it points back to `G`:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             H--I   <-- mewbranch
```

You can do this with `git reset`.

#### A side note on `git reset --hard`

Now, these drawing are fine—they're great ways to remember what's going on with *commits*—but they don't take into account the *index* and the *work-tree*.  Git's index is a complicated little thing, which sits between your current commit and your work-tree; it's perhaps best described as "the place you build your *next* commit".  The work-tree, meanwhile, is simply "where you do your work": you need this because Git's storage—including that for Git's index—is in Git's own, special, compressed Gitty format, that few if any other commands on your machine can deal with.

When you use `git reset`, you have Git do up to *three* things:

1. re-set the current branch: e.g., move `master` so that it points to some arbitrary other commit;
2. re-set the index;
3. re-set the work-tree.

Step 1 is very safe, because commits are (mostly) permanent and (entirely) read-only: moving a branch name around won't harm the commits themselves in any way.  You can just move it back and there they are again.

It's steps 2 and 3 that are not so safe.  A `--hard` reset wipes away your work-tree, changing it to match the commit you re-set to.  Any work you did that you have not committed, may be lost at this point.  (If you have committed it, of course, Git has saved it, permanently.  Well, mostly permanently.  *Reachable* commits are permanent, but that's for another topic.)

Likewise, a `--hard` or even `--mixed` reset re-sets the index.  Until you start doing advanced tricks with the index, this doesn't really matter much, since what's in the index will either be what's in a commit—this is what it starts with—or what you copied into the index from your work-tree, using `git add`.  So it's the work-tree, and hence the `--hard`, that are the big concerns here.

The short version of this, if it's not too late, :-) is: **be sure your work is either committed, or unwanted, before using `git reset --hard`.**  (If you don't really want to commit it on a branch, but don't want to *lose* it either, you can use `git stash` to save it.  This makes a commit—well, really, at least *two* commits—but the commits that `git stash` makes are on *no* branch, which is a little odd.)

Comment: One of the most explanatory answers about git. +1